# Как закрыть уведомление по истечении времени?

Tags: jquery, cookie

Уведомлению с самого начала даётся атрибут `display:none;`.

Если пользователь его не закрывал, то оно отображается, а если закрыл, то не отображается, ну это логично (реализовано).

Я пытаюсь добавить в код (не получается): если пользователь не закрывает уведомление, то оно закрывается автоматически через 10 минут, и записывает в *cookie*.

Эти 10 минут тоже записываются в *cookie* **(нужно общее время на сайте)**, по истечению 10 минут уведомление закрывается.

```js
<script src="http://ruseller.com/lessons/les667/demo/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
function hide_block(id){$("#"+id).slideUp();return false;}
function show_block(id){$("#"+id).fadeIn();return false;}
if($.cookie("not_registered_hide")){hide_block("not_registered");}
if($.cookie('not_registered_hide') === null) {show_block("not_registered");}
$("#not_registered-close-link").click(function() {hide_block("not_registered");$.cookie("not_registered_hide",'true',{expires: 365, path: '/'});});
});
</script>
```

```html
<div id="not_registered" style="display:none;">
<div id="not_registered-close"><a href="#" id="not_registered-close-link"></a></div>
<div id="not_registered_info">
<b>Уважаемый посетитель</b>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что именно не получается? Выполнить функцию по истечению 10 минут? Используйте window.setTimeout( my_function, 600000)

Comment: нужно общее время на сайте по cookie